# Can not return a collection as an array after it has been filtered

Tags: laravel

I am currently having an issue with laravel where an Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection is always being returned as an object rather than an array - causing problems with my vue components.

```
Route::get('/users', function (Request $request) {

    $users = User::all();

    $filtered = $users->filter( function ($user) {

            if($user->can('viewAny', 'App\Module')){
                return true;
            }
    });

    return $filtered;

}
```

Anything that goes through the filter refuses to convert to an array either implicitly or explicitly:

```
return User::all(); //Returns Array

return $filtered; //Returns object
return $filtered->toArray(); //Returns object?!
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Laravel version is 5.8 and a typical User object in $filtered looks like:

```
3: {
id: 4,
first_name: "Alexandrea",
last_name: "Lind",
email: "russel.oda@example.net",
email_verified_at: "2019-09-25 20:35:03",
created_at: "2019-09-25 20:35:03",
updated_at: "2019-09-25 20:35:03",
is_admin: false,
cycle: 2019,
widening_access_pricing: 0,
can_comment: 1,
can_comment_without_approval: 0,
email_consent: "2019-09-25 20:35:03",
affiliate_id: null,
purchases: [
  {
  id: 28,
  payment_intent_id: "pi_1FoAWUAsJiXFAGV72unvUP6a",
  status: "succeeded",
  user_id: 4,
  product: null,
  module_id: 6,
  created_at: "2019-12-10 15:21:14",
  updated_at: "2019-12-10 15:21:16"
  }
],
completion_records: [
]
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you dont need the data keyed by the 'id' of the records you can call `values` on the Collection to reset the keys:

```
return $filtered->values();
```

JSON doesn't have the ability to represent an associative array as an array, it has to represent it as an object. A zero-indexed array can be represented as an array in JSON as its keys are sequential so don't need to be represented in any special way.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `values`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-values)

Comment: Thanks, this works.  Why do the missing keys cause a problem?

Comment: because an associative array is an object in JSON, a zero-indexed array is an array in JSON

Answer (score 1):

I have recently faced the similar issue, you just have to call all() method after filtering collection, here is the code snippet of collection filter in laravel docs.

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4]);

$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value > 2;
});

$filtered->values();
```

Comment: This doesn't change what is returned in my case unfortunately

Comment: filter returns the object along with key, that's why you are not getting an array. calling values() function will work. as mentioned by@lagbox.